# Range of quadratic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a \neq 0$. What is the range of $f$?

I know that the answer is if $a<0$ then the range is $\left(-\infty,\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\right]$ and if $a>0$  the range is $\left[\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a},\infty\right)$ by graphing or the fact that the function has constant second derivative.

I would like to find the range without using any calculus or results from calculus.

Comment: How do you want to find the range without using any calculus? In fact  this function is not monotone.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Ah shit, I meant constant second derivative. Let me edit. I have no idea, thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: use complete square: $$a\left(x^2+2\frac{b}{2a}x+\frac{c}{a}\right)=a\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$$
i think this should help

Comment: I noticed this but I didn't quite see how this would help finish the argument.

Comment: you can use your arguuments above to finish the proof

Comment: Ahhh I see it actually. If $a>0$ I can show that $\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}-1$ is not in the image of the function and similarly for $a<0$. Thanks!